# Creating directory on server using PHP Script & Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android

I want to create a folder with custom folder name inside `htdocs` folder of Apache Web server using PHP Script & Android studio.

Custom folder name depends upon the data to be passed through user input in android application, PrinterID_Model_Label. Like (123_HP810c_room2)

Please help, majorly I am facing an issue in passing arguments(name) to PHP Script in string form.

[image: Android Parameters]

**Android Code**

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String string1 = "3269";
    String string2 = "HP810c";
    String string3 = "room2";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.68.84/printer/training.php" + string1 + string2 + string3);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $string1 = $_GET["string1"]);
    $string2 = $_GET["string2"]);
    $string3 = $_GET["string3"]);
    mkdir(/opt/lampp/htdocs/printer/$string1_$string2_string3);
?>
```

***I am little goofed up with mkdir command, so provide me a correct code !***

Comment: You should show your Android code. And the php code if the script does not do what it is told to do.

Comment: @greenapps i have updated my questions with code. Do help with correction in php code.

Comment: That does not look like that could work.  You do too much wrong.  Its better you first spend some days reading stackoverflow pages tagged android. Your problem is treated nearly every day. And again. And again. Just read. So many examples to find.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Code**

```
public class addprinter extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText inputid;
        private EditText model;
        private EditText label;
        private Button addprinter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_addprinter);

            inputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Aprinterid);
            model = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Aprintermodel);
            label = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Aprinterlabel);
            addprinter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addprinter);

            addprinter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new Connections().execute();
                    String id = inputid.getText().toString().trim();
                    String mod = model.getText().toString().trim();
                    String lbel = label.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id) || TextUtils.isEmpty(mod) || TextUtils.isEmpty(lbel)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Printer Added, check printer list for Verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });


        }

        private class Connections extends AsyncTask {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                try {
                    connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }

        private String connect() throws IOException {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.68.84/printer/addprinter.php");
            String id = inputid.getText().toString().trim();
            String mod = model.getText().toString().trim();
            String lbel = label.getText().toString().trim();
            String all = (id + mod + lbel);
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("all", all));
                // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("model",mod));
                // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("label",lbel));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        }
    }
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

 $stringOne = $_POST["all"];
if (file_exists($stringOne)) 
{
    echo "The folder exists";
} 
else 
{
    mkdir($stringOne, 0755);  
    echo "The folder created";
}
?>
```

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.printerdetect.addprinter">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Aprinterid"
                android:layout_width="282dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Printer ID (Unique)"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Aprintermodel"
                android:layout_width="282dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Model"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Aprinterlabel"
                android:layout_width="282dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Label"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addprinter"
                android:layout_width="271dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Add Printer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="287dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Printer ID should be unique"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```